# How to display time series forecasted values horizontally?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I am forecasting a monthly time series data and want forecasted values to be displayed horizontally. Currently using forecast package i am getting those values nicely with prediction interval but in multiple rows.

Currently my output is as shown below

```
             Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Sep 2018           6300        5287.423 7312.577 4751.396 7848.604
Oct 2018           6300        4867.999 7732.001 4109.944 8490.056
Nov 2018           6300        4546.164 8053.836 3617.740 8982.260
Dec 2018           6300        4274.845 8325.155 3202.793 9397.207
Jan 2019           6300        4035.808 8564.192 2837.217 9762.783
```

But i want something like this

```
Sep-18  Oct-18  Nov-18  Dec-18  Jan-19
6300    6300    6300    6300    6300
```

I am just interested in point forecast.This is to make visualisation easier as i have a handful of series to forecast. I will then just rbind each series forecasted values.

Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)

data =  ts(c(3000,3500,2700,4200,5000,5300,5800,6300),start = c(2018,1),frequency=12)           
model <- auto.arima(data)
f <- forecast(model,5)
f
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ouput of `"forecast"` function is `"ts"` class, so you should convert it to `"dataframe"` and then transpose a subset of it :

```
t(as.data.frame(f)[1])
```

Comment: This will give this error `Error in f[, c(1, 2)] : incorrect number of dimensions`. It is `ts` class.

Comment: Yes it does. Good job!

Comment: @see-king_of_knowledge ur welcome, dont remember to upvote and accept the answer, tnx.

Comment: I don't think I can accept the answer since it is not my question

Comment: @joy_1379 Don't remember to upvote and accept the answer, tnx.